# How to make sense of the Fourier transform of this distribution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

I want to compute the Fourier transform of this distribution:

$$D(f)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t,t^2) \frac{dt}{t}$$

($f$ a Schwartz function on $\mathbb{R}^2$, the integral interpreted with a Cauchy principal value)

Then, with a bit of faith in the good of the world in the step where the integrals are interchanged:

\begin{align}
\hat{D}(f) &= D(\hat{f})=\int_\mathbb{R} \hat{f}(t,t^2) \frac{dt}{t} =\int_\mathbb{R} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) e^{-i(xt+yt^2)} d(x,y) \frac{dt}{t}\\
&\overset{\text{faith}}{=} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y)\int_\mathbb{R}  e^{-i(xt+yt^2)} \frac{dt}{t} d(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f g
\end{align}

where (purely symbolically),

$$g(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{t} e^{-i(\alpha t+\beta t^2)} dt$$

Now I have two problems,

1. How to remove the dependence on faith?
2. Is $g$ (that is, $\hat{D}$) a function, i.e. does that integral above make sense in some way for $(\alpha,\beta)\not=(0,0)$? If yes, is it maybe bounded? Or maybe even smooth?

**Update:**

- I believe the answer to 1. is to consider truncations, i.e. integrate only over $a\le |t|\le b$ and then always prove things uniformly in those parameters.
- I have shown $\hat{D}$ (i.e. $g$) to be a function and that it is in fact bounded.
- Now I'm missing only the smoothness. As a comment suggests, there may be no smoothness along $\beta=0$.

Comment: a little remark: $\partial g/\partial\alpha=-i\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-i(\alpha t+\beta t^2)} dt$ is quite computable and smooth for $\beta\neq 0$. To justify things maybe try to multiply $D$ by $\exp(-\epsilon(x^2+y^2))$ and then take the limit $\epsilon\to0$.

Comment: @user8268, Thanks for your remark! Its very helpful. But how do you compute $\partial g/\partial \alpha$? I agree adding a convergence factor like that makes things converge, but how do I guarantee that after taking the limit $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, I get back what I want and not something completely different (I can't interchange limit and integral).

Comment: I irresponsibly meant something like: if $E_\epsilon:=xe^{-\epsilon x^2}D$ then $E_\epsilon(\hat f)=\int f(x,y)[\int\exp(-ixt-iyt^2-\epsilon t^2 dt]dxdy$ without any problem. For $f$ with a compact support and away from $y=0$ you can take the limit $\epsilon\to 0$ in the integral (converges uniformly in $x,y$) and actually compute it. At $y=0$ there should be a singularity.